# Android - Top of screen not showing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm having a bit of an issue with my app when I run it in the emulator/ on my device.

There is a blue rectangle on the top portion of the screen which covers a drop down menu (the three little dots). I was wondering if anyone knew what this is or how to get rid of it.

[image: This is the thing thats causing a bit of an issue]

Comment: link your xml for this activity / fragment. It looks like a Toolbar and the 3-dot option menu would appear so link your activities code as well unless you are inflating the menu in a fragment

Comment: Sorry Lucas, but im kind of new to this so what would be the best way of linking the xml?

Comment: No problem, go to the xml file that you are showing the image for (main_activity.xml is an example) under your layout folder you will find it. Then edit your post and hit the spacebar 4 times and paste the code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that is the Android ActionBar or ToolBar at the top of your screen, unless you have specifically coded that bar in your XML layout.  To hide the ActionBar or ToolBar for this activity, set the activity theme in AndroidManifest.xml to a theme that does not show the bar, such as NoTitleBar:

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Or if you are seeing this bar in all your activities, and want to hide it everywhere, set the theme NoTitleBar for your entire app in AndroidManifest.XML:

```
 <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Probably your apptheme in styles.xml is currently set to a theme that has the ActionBar or ToolBar.